# Are implied DO loops inefficient?

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I have an array initialization based on an implied do loop, given an odd size `N`.

```
J=(N+1)/2
XLOC(1:N) = (/ (I-J, I=1,N) /)
```

In the context of F90+ is it recommended to use the (/ .. /) syntax, or is more efficient to use a `FORALL` statement.

Example: for `N=19` then `XLOC=(-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)`

How else would you initialize this array?

---

Edit 1

How would you initialize this array with more readable code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such a simple construct both are likely to lead to the same code because compilers are good at optimizing.   The FORALL statement is not so much a looping statement but an initialization statement that has many restrictions that can inhibit optimizations.  If a simple loop will work, I'd use it.

Also see this previous answer: [Do Fortran 95 constructs such as WHERE, FORALL and SPREAD generally result in faster parallel code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122099/do-fortran-95-constructs-such-as-where-forall-and-spread-generally-result-in-fas)

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason they should be less efficient that actual do loops. If you find a case, where they are, report it as an missed optimization bug to your compiler vendor!