# Fortran forall restrictions

Tags: loops, fortran, fortran95

I tried to use `forall` to allocate dynamic arrays, but gfortran didn't like that. I also found out that `write` statements are forbidden in a `forall` block ,and I suspect `read` statements are too.

What other functions/operations are not permitted in a `forall` block?

Exactly what is this construct for, besides sometimes replacing `do` loops when order doesn't matter? I thought it would make coding more legible and elegant, especially showing when the order of operations are not important, but it seems quite restrictive with what operations can be done inside a `forall`.

What are the reasons for these restrictions, i.e. what do they protect/prevent the user from messing up? Is it a good idea to use `forall`? If so, for what purposes?

Right now in the code I'm working on there is only one `forall` block, and if I translated it all out in `do` loops it would give four nested loops. Which way is better?

Comment: Doesn't FORALL require PURE procedures & functions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is not much need for `FORALL` and `WHERE` constructs nowadays. They were introduced as part of Fortran 95 (minor extension to Fortran 90), mostly for the purpose of optimization, when code vectorization was a major thing in HPC. The reason that `FORALL` is so limited in application is exactly because it was designed for loop optimization. Also note that, `FORALL` is not a looping construct, but assignment. Thus, only assignment statements are allowed inside the block. In theory, `DO` loops give explicit instructions about the order of indices that the processor is going to loop over. A `FORALL` construct allows the compiler to choose the most optimal order based on how the array is stored in memory. However, this has lost meaning over time, since modern compilers are very good at `DO` loop vectorizations and you are not likely to notice any improvement by using `FORALL`.

See a nice discussion on `FORALL` and `WHERE` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4141572/827297)

If you are worried about code performance, you may rather want to consider a different compiler - [PGI](http://www.pgroup.com/) or [ifort](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-compilers/). From my own experience, gfortran is suitable for development, but not really for HPC. You will notice up to several times faster execution with code compiled with pgf90 or ifort.

Answer (score 8):

`Forall` construct proved to be really too restrictive and is mostly useful only for array operations. For exact limitations see [IBM Fortran - FORALL](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlf101l.doc/xlflr/forcons.htm). Less restrictive is a `do concurrent` construct of Fortran 2008. Even `read` and `write` statements are allowed there. See [Intel Fortran - DO CONCURRENT](http://denali.princeton.edu/IntelXe2011/compiler_f/main_for/lref_for/source_files/statement_do_concurrent.htm) and [New features of Fortran 2008](ftp://ftp.nag.co.uk/sc22wg5/N1701-N1750/N1729.pdf).

Comment: Not many compilers support Fortran 2008 yet, though. I'm using gfortran, the latest stable version (4.6?)

Comment: Gfortran 4.6 has partial support of it http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Fortran+2008+status and http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Fortran-2008-status.html, that claims support for `do concurrent` in newest gfortran.