# Smart summation in FOR(mula) TRAN(slation)

Tags: algorithm, fortran, fortran90, fortran95

Well, today I'm here with this doubt...

I want to write this equation in Fortran:

[image]

Of course I can take the "classic" approach and write it like this:

```
 do i=1,N
        ac=0.0
        do j=i+1,M
            ac=ac+A(i,j)*B(j)
        enddo
        B(i)=(B(i)-ac)/A(i,i)
  enddo
```

But since I'm writing in Fortran, I would like to write it with an expression that looks like "more like the original" and, thus, compact. I was thinking in something like:

```
forall(i=1:N,j=i+1:M)
    B(i)=(B(i)- <MySummationExpression(A(i,j)*B(j))> )/A(i,i)
endforall
```

Expression that looks much more like the original. But the thruth is that I'm having a hard time finding a way to write the summation expression in a simple and compact way. Of course that I can write a function "`real function summation(<expression>,<lower bound>, <upper bound>`)", but since we're talking about Fortran I thought that there should be a simple (maybe intrinsic(?)) way of writing it.

So there is a compact way to write that expression, or I have to take the uglier way (two explicit loops)?

**EDIT:** In the actual code `x` is a two dimensional array, with one solution in each column. So using the intrinsic function `sum` that, up to here, seems like a great idea (as @alexander-vogt shown in his answer) leads to almost the same "compacticity" of the code:

```
do j=1,size(B,2)
        do i=nA,1,-1
            B(i,j)=(B(i,j)-sum(A(i,i+1:nA)*B(i+1:nA,j)))/A(i,i)
        enddo
 enddo
```

Comment: A valid effort, but "smarter" written code is often less readable and may come with free bugs. Write code in the way that is easiest for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
do i=1,N
  B(i) = (B(i) - sum( A(i+1:M,i) * B(i+1:M) )) / A(i,i)
enddo
```

(Please notice that I changed the indexing of matrix `A`, Fortran is column major! )

As we are re-using `B` for the result, this loop has to be done in ascending order. I'm not sure it's possible to do this using `forall` (isn't it up to the compiler to choose how to proceed? - see [Fortran forall restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602596/fortran-forall-restrictions)).

Writing the result into a new vector `C` does not overwrite `B` and can be executed in any order:

```
forall ( i=1:N )
  C(i) = (B(i) - sum( A(i+1:M,i) * B(i+1:M) )) / A(i,i)
endforall
```

Comment: I see that you had changed the indexing, but in that way the result is wrong. I'll investigate further why.

Comment: Well, just changing to `A(i,i+1:M)` I get the same results as with the code in the original question... The matrix `A` has to be transposed to work with the solution I provided ;-)